# JSON Parsing in Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight, json

I have a bunch of little JSON object fragments of the form:

```
{ id: "wow", foo: 45.4, bar: "hello, world!" }
```

By "a bunch" I mean about 6 GB worth. :-) (And yes, I know, this isn't technically JSON. The full story is that it originally came from YAML data, but I find that most "JSON" parsers can handle this subset of YAML just fine.)

Currently, I use Netonsoft's JSON parser with the line:

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
```

This works well for me, but I am porting my WinForms app to Silverlight 3.0 (and onward to 4.0 once I get the chance).

From Googling around, I see that there is some "DataContractSuperJavaScriptExSerializer2" library from Microsoft that does JSON parsing.

Should I use that library, or is there something better on the horizon? I'm 30 mins away from writing my JSON parser so that I can ensure that it is efficient, but I thought I would see if there is anything else worth looking at in the Silverlight 3 world.

Comment: I take it the Newtonsoft parser doesn't work in Silverlight? It's open-source - you could consider extracting a subset that does work in Silverlight from that code.

Comment: @Joel, let's call that plan Z. I would prefer to write my own parser before I go and tear that thing up. I never liked their object model anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a referece to System.Json and System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

```
#using System.Json;

using (var reader = new StringReader(jsonText))
{
    var response = JsonValue.Load(reader) as JsonObject;

    /// parse your code here
}
```